# Haskell - Generalized Composition

Tags: haskell, operators, typeclass, composition

I've been trying to implement a generalized composition operator `<$.$>` such that:

```
f <$.$> g1 <$.$> g2 <$.$> .. <$.$> gn = \x1 x2 .. xn -> f (g1 x1) (g2 x2) .. (gn xn)
```

It /should/ be possible to implement this with type classes and some additional language extensions. My main idea was to make the operator mark each level so that the next operators will compose the appropriate arguments.

Unfortunately I am getting stuck in the implementation details since I am not yet experienced with such abuse of type classes and I am not completely aware of which language extensions are required. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a fine question as it stands, but my curiosity overwhelms me: why have you been trying to implement that?

Comment: @DanielWagner for educational reasons / fun

Comment: You might compare with `f <$> g1 <*> g2 <*> ... <*> gn == \x -> f (g1 x) (g2 x) ... (gn x)`.

Comment: @chepner I am aware of the Applicative usage of functions but it requires `gi`s of same first argument type and the end result is a single argument function.

Comment: My point is that you have a similar, asymmetric requirement with the first function in the chain. `f <$.$> g <$.$> h` won't do what you want for the same reasons that `f <*> g <*> h` and `f <$> g <*> h` are different; your desired outcome is closer the latter than the former. I'd describe your outcome as being more similar to a generalized `on` than a generalized composition.

Comment: @chepner I am not sure that a generalized `on` is that similar, it already functions differently for two argument functions while the required operator acts as composition for single argument functions. As for requiring a different first operator, I thought that since I will /probably/ need language extensions I could overoad it's usage if needed - I guess this is c++ metaprogramming haunting me.